# How do you remove the square bracket in my json file robot framework?

Tags: json, robotframework, appium-android

How do I get only the number in json file for robot framework?
i am now using this

```
xpath=//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='${StoryPhotonumber}']
```

I get this

```
//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='[1]']
```

I want this

```
xpath=//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='1']
```

json file

```
{
"number": 1
}
```

robotframework file

```
${Story}=    get value from json     ${json_obj}     $.number
Set Global Variable    ${StoryPhotonumber}     ${Story}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to do this but for me I'll create a user-defined keyword like below:

```
import re

def format_xpath(xpath, js):

    a = re.sub("(\[\d\]'\])+", "", xpath)
    b = "xpath=" + a + str(js["number"]) + "']"

    return b 


xpath = "//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='[1]']"

js = {"number": 1}

print(format_xpath(xpath, js))

Output: xpath=//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='1']
```

Robot:

```
${js}=      get value from json  ${json_obj}
${Story}=   Format xpath  ${xpath}  ${js}     
Set Global Variable       ${Story}
```